# How to prevent rows with default values being submitted to MySQL database

Tags: php, forms, default-value

I have a form with 2 sections, each of which starts out with one row and to which further rows can be added using a script.  You can see the form on the bottom of [this page](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference/index.html).

The form uses default values and I am looking for a way of not submitting rows that contain default values (to both MySQL database and via email).  Because people may only complete one row (i.e. at Waged or Unwaged rate), often I will only want one row of information to be submitted. The current code for the form is below.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Nick

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="booking" action="bookingengine.php">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Waged/Organisation Rate</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="name[]">
            <input type="text" name="email[]">
            <input type="text" name="organisation[]">
            <input type="text" name="position[]">
        </p>
        <p><span class="add">Add person</span></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2>Unwaged Rate</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="name2[]">
            <input type="text" name="email2[]">
        </p>
        <p><span class="add">Add person</span></p>
    </fieldset>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit and proceed to payment page" class="submit-button" /></p>

</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var defaults = {
        'name[]':           'Name',
    'name2[]':           'Name',
        'email[]':          'Email',
     'email2[]':          'Email',
        'organisation[]':   'Organisation',
        'position[]':       'Position'

    };

    // separating set and remove
    // note that you could add "defaults" as an arg if you had different
    // defaults for different fieldsets
    var setDefaults = function(inputElements) {
        $(inputElements).each(function() {
            var d = defaults[this.name];
            if (d) {
                // set with jQuery
                // we don't need the data - just check on the class
                $(this).val(d)
                    .addClass('default_value');
            }
        });
    };

    var removeDefaults = function(inputElements) {
        $(inputElements).each(function() {
           if ($(this).hasClass('default_value')) {
                $(this).val('')
                   .removeClass('default_value');
           }
        });
    };

    setDefaults(jQuery('form[name=booking] input'));

    $("span.add").click(function() {
        // get the correct fieldset based on the current element
        var $fieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset');
        var $inputset = $('p', $fieldset)
                .first()
                .clone()
                .insertBefore($('p', $fieldset).last());
        // add a remove button
        $inputset.append('<span class="remove">Remove</span>');
        setDefaults($('input', $inputset));
        // return false; (only needed if this is a link)
    });

    // use delegate here to avoid adding new 
    // handlers for new elements
    $('fieldset').delegate("span.remove", {
        'click': function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });

    // Toggles 
    $('form[name=booking]').delegate('input', {
        'focus': function() {
            removeDefaults($(this));
        },
        'blur': function() {
            // switch to using .val() for consistency
            if (!$(this).val()) setDefaults(this);
        }
    });
 }); 
 </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$emailFrom = "****";
$emailTo = "****";
$subject = "****";

$body = "****" . "\n\n";
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
$row_count2 = count($_POST['name2']);

$values = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
     // variable sanitation...
     $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'][$i]));
     $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'][$i]));
     $organisation = trim(stripslashes($_POST['organisation'][$i]));
     $position = trim(stripslashes($_POST['position'][$i]));

     // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
     // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
     $body .= "Name: " . $name . "    Email: " . $email . "  Organisation: " . $organisation . "   Position: " . $position . "\n\n";

     //prepare the values for MySQL
     $values[] = '(\'' . $name . '\',\'' . $email . '\',\'' . $organisation . '\',\'' . $position . '\')';

}

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO conference (Name, Email, Organisation, Position) VALUES "  . implode(',', $values);

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
if (!$result1) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


 $body .= "****" . "\n\n";

 $values = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
     // variable sanitation...
     $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name2'][$i]));
     $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email2'][$i]));

     // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
     // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
     $body .= "Name: " . $name . "    Email: " . $email . "\n\n";

     //prepare the values for MySQL
     $values2[] = '(\'' . $name . '\',\'' . $email . '\')';
}
$query2 = "INSERT INTO conference (Name, Email) VALUES " . implode(',', $values2);

$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
if (!$result2) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: <$emailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/conference/payment.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: WARNING - your code is susceptible to SQL injection!

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me what I need to do to make it more secure?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @Nick here is the link to the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an IF statement in PHP assuming any validation you have has returned no errors.

For example

```
// SET VARIABLES
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
// SET CORRECT VALUES
if($name2 == "Surname") { $name2 = ""; }
// RUN DB FUNCTIONS
```

I would do this for each default value allowing me to insert just what I need or want from the default values and remove or change the rest. It also means user data remains in tact.

I hope this helps you get on the right track :)

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I have yet to work out a validation method (that's the next step!).  If I do as you suggest for all default values, and a row contains only default values, will a blank row be added to my MySQL database?  Also, for the emails generated by the PHP, I would still have an entry for rows with just default values, so I would still need to work out how to prevent this.

Comment: In my opinion I think you're going about the coding the wrong way, I would break down each part and work with it independently for development, starting with knowing what data I need for what purpose, this tells me what validation I need to put in place, then I would write the validations, next insert to the database and finally email. The reason for this order is I can then work with the data correctly in programming, I can save the data first so if there is a failure with email the data is already stored and can be resent if needed, then notify who needs to know. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I'm very willing to believe I'm coding the wrong way! In terms of the data I want, for any given row the user adds data to, all fields need to be completed (i.e. no default values) and the email should be valid. Because I have 1 row in each _section_, and the user may only want to complete 1 row, I need to work out how to handle this. Either I add a remove button to each row and then get the validation code to block all default values, forcing the user to remove unwanted rows, or I skip validation on rows with only default values, and don't submit these rows to email/MySQL.

Comment: @Nick I don't believe there is always a right and wrong way to cod, just better and not so good ways (unless you have coding errors that is!). If I were you I would put in place validation of the data, on no validation errors submit to the processing script that will remove any default values and then handle the data inserting to mySQL then send out the email. Pretty simple when put like that I think :) Sorry about the delay in getting back to you also. I hope my feedback has helped you. Also, if you think my answer is good could you please accept it? Cheers mate

Comment: Thanks Ryan, and sorry for being slow in getting back to you.  Your method of preventing default values from being entered into a MySQL database works fine.  I am also implementing a validation method based on your suggestion, and am trying to work out how to best combine these to get the data I need.

Comment: No problem Nick, I'm glad I could help you out. There are a ton of validation options out there and for the required fields, you could amend the code to return an error quite easily. JQuery is often an easy way to put in place an effective yet "pretty" validation with minimal coding that does not require the page to be submitted - less clicks = better user experience. Good luck and thanks mate